# Problem with STIX2 in TeXLive 2019

Tags: texlive, stix, texlive-2019

I just installed TeXLive 2019 on a Windows 10 system. The following file generates an error:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}

\begin{document}
$\int x$ % works
\[ \int \] % xdvipdfmx:fatal: Charsets data not available No output PDF file written.
\end{document}
```

I tested it on a TL2018 (`XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX)`) and it compiles without problem. Also lualatex from TL2019 successfully compiles it.

Is there a problem with my system, or should I report a bug?

Comment: No problem on macOS with MacTeX.

Comment: If XeTeX isn’t finding the font on a new installation, but LuaTeX can,, you might re-run `fc-cache -r`..

Comment: For what its worth I can confirm same problem New TexLive 2019 on Win 10 x64 fully uptodate packages (basic installation++ numerous others but admittedly not full) as above LuaLaTeX works XeLaTeX does not (fc-cache -r makes no difference nor does running update font mapping etc.)

Comment: can you check \sum also seems to be affected

Comment: No it's not affected, `\sum` compiles in both inline and display math.

Comment: I ran `xelatex` with `-no-pdf` followed by `xdvipdfmx` with `-vv` option. The last lines (in file with \int) are `otf_cmap>> Creating ToUnicode CMap for "c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/stix2-otf/STIX2Math.otf"...`, then `xdvipdfmx:warning: Invalid CMap mapping entry. (ignored)` and `xdvipdfmx:fatal: Charsets data not available`

Comment: OK I tried forcing cache etc -vv or -vvv show multiple errors and I still cant get \sum to work either so that's a bigger mystery as to why we have a difference I could accept we both had one bad glyph if that was the cause but now I am more confused why building fonts seems to differ

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the newest xdvipdfmx. I run your example without problem, then updated only dvipdfmx.win32  and now it fails for some math fonts. Restoring the backup resolved the problem. I will report this on the texlive list.

Comment: I just updated package dvipdfmx.win32 to revision 51028 and the above problems no longer occur.

Comment: What is the right thing to do with this question? The comment of @UlrikeFischer is the answer. I'll happily accept it if it's made an answer; or I can close my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug  in the newest xdvipdfmx.

I run your example without problem, then updated only dvipdfmx.win32 and then it failed for some math fonts. Restoring the backup resolved the problem.

I reported this on the texlive list and got the answer that it will be fixed soon.